# how to work with a list which comes from a list in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have a lists:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 = ([] for i in range(5))
```

how can I work with them in a while loop? I tried that:

```
x=1
while (x<6):

    for col in sheetG.columns[x]:
        if col.value is not None :
            list+str(x).append(col.value)
    x=x+1
```

but it doesn't work

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'str'
```

I don't know how to append a value to every list which number of a list depends on x

Comment: list refers to the data type.

Comment: What do you expect this line to do `list+str(x).append(col.value)`? As the error message says, you are trying to add a `list` to `str`, which isn't going to work. And worse yet `list` is just the name of a type, so you certainly can't add it to a variable.

Comment: Î would like to have list1.append(col.value), after x=2 list2.append(col.value) etc.

Comment: Check the answer I posted, it does the same in a Pythonic way. You could use globals() but its not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list of lists as such:

```
total_lists = [[]]

for i in xrange(4):
    total_lists.append([])
```

Then you can do:

```
while (x<6):

    for col in sheetG.columns[x]:
        if col.value is not None :
            total_lists[x].append(col.value)
    x=x+1
```

Comment: Or simply `total_lists = [[] for _ in xrange(5)]`.  
Beginners might also be tempted to do `[[]] * 5`, don't do that. You'll get a list with 5 references to the *very same* list instead of 5 different lists.